# Storing a DateTime Value in a Sortable Custom Field?

Tags: custom-field

Is there a way to store a custom field value as a datetime so it can be used to order by?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [**jQuery DatePicker**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) and save the date, and use `query_post` to show the postS in order (code [also on github](http://gist.github.com/323514)):

```
<?php
//The Query
// exactly than
query_posts('meta_key=start_date&meta_value='.date("Y-m-d"));
// or
// dates less than
// query_posts('meta_key=start_date&meta_compare=<=&meta_value='.date("Y-m-d"));
// or
// date mayor than
// query_posts('meta_key=start_date&meta_compare=>=&meta_value='.date("Y-m-d"));

//The Loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 echo the_title();
 echo "<br />";
endwhile; else:
endif;

//Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: I would recommend using a timestamp instead if `Y-m-d` format, as that will easily allow you do add `time` whenever you wish, also MySQL will be quicker at ordering by a timestamp than it will the MySQL date time format.